# React native expo - Navigate from FlatList to detail screen

Tags: react-native, expo, screen, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

React Native rookie here. I am trying to adjust the React Native expo tabbed app to my learning needs. I am currently working on Flatlists and I want to open a new screen on ressing any item of the FlatList sending as parameter on of the item's props. I have reached a certain point but can't seem to successfully complete it.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import React from 'react';
import {Image,Platform,ScrollView,StyleSheet,Text,TouchableOpacity,View,} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import SearchableFlatList from '../navigation/SearchableList';
import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';

export default function HomeScreen() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
            <SearchableFlatList/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Image
                    source={require('../assets/images/icon.png')}
                    style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                />
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
                    AgriPrices
                </Text>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: () => <LogoTitle />,
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#f4511e',},
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',},
};
```

**MainTabNavigator.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

const config = Platform.select({web: { headerMode: 'screen' },default: {},});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({Home: HomeScreen,},config);
HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (<TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-home'}/>),
};
HomeStack.path = '';

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({Links: LinksScreen,},config);
LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Info',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (<TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-information-circle'}/>),
};
LinksStack.path = '';

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({Settings: SettingsScreen,},config);
SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (<TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-settings' : 'md-settings'} />),
};
SettingsStack.path = '';

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({HomeStack,SettingsStack,LinksStack,});
tabNavigator.path = '';

export default tabNavigator;
```

**SearchableFlatlist.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import DetailsScreen from '../screens/DetailsScreen';

class MyFlatList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      error: null,
    };
    this.arrayholder = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const url = 'http://dummyurl.com';
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({data: res,error: res.error || null,loading: false,});
        this.arrayholder = res;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: '86%',
          backgroundColor: '#CED0CE',
          marginLeft: '14%',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  searchFilterFunction = text => {
    this.setState({
      value: text,
    });
    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.description.toUpperCase()} ${item.product.toUpperCase()} ${item.product.toUpperCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      data: newData,
    });
  };

  _onPress(item) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {product: item.product,description: item.description,});
  }

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        lightTheme
        round
        onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
        autoCorrect={false}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    const myicons = [
      {title: 'Cotton',file: require('../assets/images/cotton.png'),},
      {title: 'Beef',file: require('../assets/images/beef.png'),},
      {title: 'Bananas',file: require('../assets/images/banana.png'),},
      {title: 'Butter',file: require('../assets/images/butter.png'),},
      {title: 'Cocoa',file: require('../assets/images/cocoa.png'),},
      {title: 'Coffee',file: require('../assets/images/coffee.png'),},
      {title: 'Corn',file: require('../assets/images/corn.png'),},
      {title: 'Cotton',file: require('../assets/images/cotton.png'),},
      {title: 'Eggs',file: require('../assets/images/eggs.png'),},
      {title: 'Meat',file: require('../assets/images/meat.png'),},
      {title: 'Milk',file: require('../assets/images/milk.png'),},
      {title: 'Oils',file: require('../assets/images/oil.png'),},
      {title: 'Oranges',file: require('../assets/images/orange.png'),},
      {title: 'Rice',file: require('../assets/images/rice.png'),},
      {title: 'Shrimps',file: require('../assets/images/shrimp.png'),},
      {title: 'Sugar',file: require('../assets/images/sugar.png'),},
      {title: 'Tea',file: require('../assets/images/tea.png'),},
      {title: 'Tobacco',file: require('../assets/images/tobacco.png'),},
      {title: 'Wheat',file: require('../assets/images/wheat.png'),},
      {title: 'Wool',file: require('../assets/images/wool.png'),},
      {title: 'Oats',file: require('../assets/images/oat.png'),},
      {title: 'Indexes',file: require('../assets/images/index.png'),},
    ];
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              leftAvatar={{ source: myicons.filter(myitem => myitem.title === item.product)[0].file }}
              title={item.description}
              rightTitle={item.price.toString()}
              subtitle={item.date}
              onPress={() => navigate('Details', { product: item.product })}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.description}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyFlatList;
```

**DetailsScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, Image,ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function DetailsScreen() {
  var product =this.props.navigation.getParam('product', 'No Name'); //second parameter is a callback
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>The product is {this.props.navigation.state.params.product||'NoName'} /*NoName is also a callback*/</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

DetailsScreen.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: () => <LogoTitle />,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
};

class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/images/icon.png')}
            style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
          />
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
            AgriPrices
        </Text>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

I need to open DetailsScreen when I press an item of SearchableFlatList of HomeScreen by passing as paramter the *description*. With the code above, I get an error *undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')*. How can I surpass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you wrap MyFlatList and DetailsScreen with a stack navigator.

```
const finalStack = createStackNavigator(
{
    MyFlatList: MyFlatList,
    DetailsScreen: DetailsScreen
},
{
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

Once you have done this, 'this.props.navigation.navigate' will not be undefined.
As of now, there is no navigation link between these two screens.

Q: Why I choose a stack navigator?
A: As you don't want FlatList to render repeatedly on the screen switch.

Comment: In which file fo you mean? Thanks btw for your time.

Comment: In HomeScreen.js, replace  SearchableFlatList with my suggested stack navigator. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: If I add the code as you suggest, it first gives an error of inknown variable MyFlatList. So, I chnaged FlatList to SearchableFlatList in your code, as in the import. Now, it gives the same undefined error for this.props.navigation.navigate.

Comment: I gave just an idea of how it works, you were not supposed to copy that code.
Please make a working demo on https://snack.expo.io/.
It will be easier for me to help you.

Comment: MyFlatList should be SearchableFlatList in your HomeScreen.js

Comment: You should also import DetailsScreen.js in HomeScreen.js

Comment: The model is 3 Stacknavigators inside a TabNavigator, one for each tab. In the first tab (Home), I want the StackNavigator to be between Home and Details screens. I beliee the navigator model is fine but the way to call navigate is wrong.

Comment: Which file is the parent navigator for both HomeScreen and SearchableFlatList Screen?

Comment: MainTabNavigator.js but SearchableFlatList is just imported in HomeScreen. I don't want to navigate to it

Comment: This is what I'm trying to explain, both HomeScreen and SearchableFlatList Screen should be under the same navigator to support navigation. As of now, SearchableFlatList and DetailScreen are not under any navigation.

Comment: Now I get it. I replaced HomeScreen.js content with that of SearchableList.js and now everything works. Thank you so much for your patience and time with my question. Your answer is of course accepted.

Comment: No issue brother!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206509/discussion-between-raj-rohit-yadav-and-lios).